# Calculating what frequencies a dielectric can be considered perfect

Tags: electromagnetism, wave

I have a problem that is likely going to be on my E&M final this semester that my classmates and I can not figure out how to solve.  The question is

> At what frequencies can Earth be considered a perfect dielectric if \$\sigma = 5 \cdot 10^-3 S/m\$, \$\mu_r = 1\$, and \$\epsilon_r = 8\$. Can \$\alpha\$ be neglected at these frequencies?

Our professor isn't of much use, and we can't find any information in our book or lecture slides (that our professor has stolen from another university) that can help us.

Note: \$\alpha\$ is this case is in reference to propagation constant \$\gamma = \alpha + j\beta\$.

Answer (score 2):

A material is a perfect dielectric if the conductivity is zero, in which case the AC resistance would approach infinity. My initial guess without doing any research would be that you have to find the frequency at which the skin depth of the earth becomes effectively zero. The skin depth is given using the following formula:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=skin+depth+formula

There is a simplified version of the equation but I can't remember it off the top of my head.

Comment: Using that equation, you end up with it in the form

$$ \delta = \frac{C}{f} $$

where $$C$$ is some constant based on the other properties of the dielectric.  Then your frequency at which it becomes "perfect" is arbitrary depending on what precision you want.

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that equation doesn't help for solving for frequency when the skin depth is 0, it's just as f approaches infinity, and you can arbitrarily pick a skin depth to get any frequency you want.

Comment: A little more value add, especially information that is practical and applicable as opposed to a formula reference, would be nice.

Comment: From the wolframalpha link provided above, the formula reduces down to

$$ \delta = \frac{C}{f} $$

where C is dependent on sigma, mu, and epsilon, and f is frequency.  Since OP said that you want to find the frequency at which skin depth is 0, this is unsolvable, since you would then have

$$ 0 = \frac{C}{f} \Rightarrow f \to \infty$$

You could pick a value for skin depth that you would be considering to be "close enough to zero", but it would be arbitrary.

I don't have any more information for the problem, either.  That is literally the entire thing typed out above.

Answer (score 1):

For a material to be a perfect dielectric, sigma (conductivity) << w (angular frequency) * E (epsilon). Also sigma should approach zero.

Comment: This does not answer the question and is more a comment than anything. If you read the other answer, this is already discussed there.